# adding app to fanpage... fanpage not showing up on "Add Page Tab"

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook, facebook-like

So I followed the directions on facebook to add my app (which is a tab) to my fanpage:

"Facebook Page administrators can add your app directly to their Page by navigating to the following URL: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/pagetab?app_id=YOUR_APP_ID&next=YOUR_URL, where YOUR_APP_ID and YOUR_URL can be found in your app settings."

And I got the the Add Page Tab page as described above but when I click on "choose facebook pages" drop-down, the fanpage I want to add the app to is not listed. I'm an admin on the fanpage... any idea of what is wrong?

Comment: did you setup your `Page Tab URL` and `Secure Page Tab URL` in your application settings?

Comment: I added the url that I want to be included within facebook to the page tab url (the website that I created to be put in the iframes)... was I suppose to put the fanpage's url here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using this form http://addtopage.muffinsdeluxe.com/
It will generate the correct link you need to add the app to your page.

Good luck :)